# Fade effect affecting my output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my script :

```
<div id ="success-message">

</div>


 <script>
 $('form.subscribe').on('submit', function() {
var that = $(this),
url = that.attr('action'),
method = that.attr('method'),
data ={};
 that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
  var that = $(this),
  name = that.attr('name'),
  value = that.val();

data[name] = value;
 });

$.ajax({
url: url,
type:method,
data: data,
success: function(response){


$('#success-message').html(response)

}

});

return false;


 });

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#success-message').fadeOut('slow');
}, 2000); // <-- time in milliseconds
    </script>
```

I have an ajax function that gives me either an error message or a success message depending on what your input was on the form.

The messages that I get come from this php script:

```
<?php
    header("Refresh:7; url=contact.php");
    $email = $_POST['subscribefield'];

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Dit emailadres klopt niet";
        die();
    }

    $to = "flash1996mph@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
    $body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    echo "U heeft zich zojuist aangemeld voor de vandenberg nieuwsbrief";
?>
```

I am now outputting the 2 echo's from the php file in a div called success-message, so far so good. but i wanted to make the message dissapear after a while so i added this function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#success-message').fadeOut('slow');
}, 2000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

but now it only shows me the message when theres an error for example, now it only shows me a message when the form is not filled properly. and when its correctly filled i get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After you write the response to the div, make sure you show the div again if you've already hidden it.

Something like:

```
$('#success-message').html(response).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the `setTimeout()` code block inside the success function. When you are running the code it is making `#success-message` css to `display:none` immediately.

So, you can fix it Like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
type:method,
data: data,
success: function(response){

$('#success-message').html(response);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#success-message').fadeOut('slow');
}, 2000);

}

});
```